# Comparing 我一个弟兄们 with 我的一个兄弟

Tags: grammar

《庭审现场》２０１５１２２６ 谁在说谎 http://news.cntv.cn/2015/12/26/VIDE1451136647389475.shtml. Civil case plaintiff 李付成, at time mark 01:42, says： `我一个弟兄们（有三间老房子）`. Would 我的一个兄弟 (or at least 我的一个弟兄) not be more usual? Any comment on the first version?

Comment: reason for giving 我的一个兄弟 as first alternative （and not 我的一个弟兄）： as confirmed by various dictionaries 弟兄 is used more likely than 兄弟 in the more abstract sense，i.p. for brethren （cf. Bible）

Comment: Strictly speaking it is indeed ungrammatical and it sounds awkward to my ears, but informal speech doesn't require much precision. Some people use 一个 in daily conversation to refer to something/somebody they wouldn't like to specify. In such a case, 一个 doesn't mean exactly *one*.

Comment: It might be a mishearing (by the subtitler), such as `我一个弟兄么有三间老房子`.

Comment: "弟兄么"  as NP (noun phrase) seems rather uncommon,  么些弟兄 exists and maybe  弟兄么些 (么些 added as an afterthought) is acceptable

Comment: some users might be reminded of "我一个哥们儿（姐们儿）＂even though the plaintiff in this case would hardly say "one of my buddies/pals/mates".

Comment: @user6065 this usage of 么 as in 我一个弟兄么 is not uncommon in spoken language. I agree with songyuanyao's speculation.

Comment: cf。现代汉语词典： 娘们（２）（方）称成年妇女（含轻蔑意，可以用于单数）（３）（方）妻子 e.g.in《第十一根手指》 http://www.ty2016.net/horror/fyqm03/
find 现在这个冷傲的娘们终于认识到了我们的重要性， 这个娘们不会对林涛动什么坏心思吧？where 这个娘们 refers to a single individual,

Comment: another example of 们 denoting  singular: 大老爷们 1.方言。指成年以上的男子。 老爷们儿 : 〈方〉①指成年男子：谁家的～不干活，光让老娘们儿去干？ ②指丈夫（zhàng·fu）：她～在外地做买卖。 http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/191979.html

Answer (score 3):

**我一个弟兄们** is grammatically incorrect: **一个** (=1) conflicts with **们** (>1).
I watched the video in question. The interviewee actually said **我一个弟兄**. It is the subtitle that added a **们** at the end.

Answer (score 1):

I think 兄弟 is used most often to mean something like "my buddy / pal", whereas 弟兄 has a military connotation. It's often used in war movies by soldiers referring to each other.

I'd expect 兄弟 to be used more often by people talking about a familial, personal relationship, and 弟兄 to refer to a person you got to know in some formal organization like the military.

The 们 is probably adapted from 哥们, which is colloquial and can refer to a single person.